# (Julia) Not able suppress output using semicolon when assigning variable inside an IF statement

Tags: if-statement, julia, suppress

Why does adding a semicolon in an IF ELSE statement is unable to suppress the output display?

[Unable to suppress output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCkPP.png)

Comment: Hey Edward! Please take a moment to try and re-phrase this as a complete question and make the image a separate link from the rest of the question text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed as the [Julia Manual explains](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/getting-started/):

> If an expression is entered into an interactive session with a trailing semicolon, its value is not shown.

However, this statement refers to the whole entered expression. In your case the whole expression includes the `if` part so you should write:

```
if condition
    ...
else
    ...
end;
```

(note the semicolon afer `end`)

In particular note, as explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#man-conditional-evaluation) in the Julia Manual, that:

> `if` blocks also return a value, which may seem unintuitive to users coming from many other languages. This value is simply the return value of the last executed statement in the branch that was chosen

Putting `;` after `end` suppresses printing of the value returned by the `if` block.